# Sign in with Apple-web and firebase (Ionic)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, apple-sign-in

I am trying to integrate apple sign in with Firebase to my Ionic web app.

I configured all the key/service IDs over the Apple developer account and Firebase.

Code looks like this:

```
  loginWithAppleWeb() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');

    provider.addScope('email');
    provider.addScope('name');

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(result => {
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });   }
```

Calling Apple sign-in seems to work, it opens a window where I can log in with my Apple ID. Afterwards it even shows my app in my Apple ID settings, but not in Firebase.
[image]

After the sign-in process I get an error from the Google API:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from https://appleid.apple.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://myapp-test.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], cookieList=[]}}",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from https://appleid.apple.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://myapp-test.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], cookieList=[]}}",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the response comes from this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=XXXX
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add my domain in the apple developer settings. I don't know exactly what I did but remember I changed some stuff with a serviceID.
Maybe this helps a little: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UafqYgRoIC0&ab_channel=Fireship